# Android ListView with 2 TextViews and 1 Button

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to create a ListView with 2 TextViews and 1 Button. When the users click in the button the activity will finish(); and pass the result to another view. I followed [this tutorial](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html) . But for some reason when i click to start that activity my application crashes! Here is the 3 files from my app that are relevant.

List Structure Data:

```
public class formulasListData {
private String formulasName;
private String formulasDefinition;

public formulasListData(String formulasName, String formulasDefinition) {
    super();
    this.formulasName = formulasName;
    this.formulasDefinition = formulasDefinition;
}

public String getFormulasName() {
    return formulasName;
}

public void setFormulasName(String formulasName) {
    this.formulasName = formulasName;
}

public String getFormulasDefinition() {
    return formulasDefinition;
}

public void setFormulasDefinition(String formulasDefinition) {
    this.formulasDefinition = formulasDefinition;
    }
}
```

The List Adapter:

```
public class formulasListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
private Context context;
private List<formulasListData> formulasList;

public formulasListAdapter(Context context, List<formulasListData> formulasList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.formulasList = formulasList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return formulasList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return formulasList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
    formulasListData entry = formulasList.get(position);
    if(rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formulas_row, null);
    }

    TextView formulasName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.formulas_name);
    formulasName.setText(entry.getFormulasName());

    TextView formulasDefinition = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.formulas_definition);
    formulasDefinition.setText(entry.getFormulasDefinition());

    Button btnSelect = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.selectFormula);
    btnSelect.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    btnSelect.setFocusable(false);
    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnSelect.setTag(entry);

    return rowView;
}
@Override

public void onClick(View view) {
    formulasListData entry = (formulasListData) view.getTag();
    }

}
```

And the activity that should display the list.

```
public class FormulasList extends Activity {

private static final int FORMULA_0 = 0;
private static final int FORMULA_1 = 1;
private static final int FORMULA_2 = 2;
private static final int FORMULA_3 = 3;
private static final int FORMULA_4 = 4;
private static final int FORMULA_5 = 5;
private static final int FORMULA_6 = 6;
// private static final int FORMULA_7 = 7;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    ListView formulasListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.formulas_list);
    formulasListView.setClickable(true);
    final List<formulasListData> formulasList = new ArrayList<formulasListData>();

    final String[] formulasName = new String[] {"Circunference of a Circle:",
                                "Area of a Circle:",
                                "Volume of a Sphere:",
                                "Area Triangle:", 
                                "Area Square:",
                                "Volume of a Cube:",
                                "Pithagorean Theorem:"};
    final String[] formulasDefinition = new String[] {"2 × π × r",
                                        "π × r²",
                                        "(4/3) × π × r³",
                                        "(b × h)/2",
                                        "side²",
                                        "side³",
                                        "a² + b² = c²"};        
    // formulasList.add(new formulasListData(formulasName, formulasDefinition));
    formulasList.add(new formulasListData(formulasName[0], formulasDefinition[0]));
    formulasList.add(new formulasListData(formulasName[1], formulasDefinition[1]));
    formulasList.add(new formulasListData(formulasName[2], formulasDefinition[2]));
    formulasList.add(new formulasListData(formulasName[3], formulasDefinition[3]));
    formulasList.add(new formulasListData(formulasName[4], formulasDefinition[4]));
    formulasList.add(new formulasListData(formulasName[5], formulasDefinition[5]));
    formulasList.add(new formulasListData(formulasName[6], formulasDefinition[6]));

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SettingsActivity.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SettingsActivity.newTheme = settings.getInt("themeCustom", 0);

     if(SettingsActivity.newTheme == SettingsActivity.THEME_DARK) {
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        } else if(SettingsActivity.newTheme == SettingsActivity.THEME_LIGHT){
            setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        } else if(SettingsActivity.newTheme == SettingsActivity.THEME_COLORS) {
            setTheme(R.style.ColorsTheme);
        } else { 
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
         }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulas);

    formulasListAdapter adapter = new formulasListAdapter(this, formulasList);

    formulasListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long index) {
            Intent intent= getIntent();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            switch (position) {
            case FORMULA_0:
                b.putString("key0", formulasDefinition[0]);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case FORMULA_1:
                b.putString("key0", formulasDefinition[1]);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case FORMULA_2:
                b.putString("key0", formulasDefinition[2]);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case FORMULA_3:
                b.putString("key0", formulasDefinition[3]);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case FORMULA_4:
                b.putString("key0", formulasDefinition[4]);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case FORMULA_5:
                b.putString("key0", formulasDefinition[5]);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case FORMULA_6:
                b.putString("key0", formulasDefinition[6]);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }               
        }
    });     
    formulasListView.setAdapter(adapter);   
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!!

EDIT: Here is the LogCat

```
05-01 20:06:54.436: D/libEGL(4820): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
05-01 20:06:54.456: D/libEGL(4820): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
05-01 20:06:54.466: D/libEGL(4820): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
05-01 20:06:54.486: D/OpenGLRenderer(4820): Enabling debug mode 0
05-01 20:06:54.536: D/dalvikvm(4820): GC_CONCURRENT freed 170K, 4% free 7509K/7808K, paused 4ms+10ms, total 38ms
05-01 20:06:59.976: D/AndroidRuntime(4820): Shutting down VM
05-01 20:06:59.976: W/dalvikvm(4820): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cde930)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gabilheri.marcuscalculatorv2/com.gabilheri.marcuscalculatorv2.FormulasList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at com.gabilheri.marcuscalculatorv2.FormulasList.onCreate(FormulasList.java:30)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-01 20:06:59.976: E/AndroidRuntime(4820):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can we have the logcat printout, to know why the application is crashing

Comment: Edited with the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulas);
To the start of the method.  Right after the super call.

You are trying to use gui controls before initializing the activity layout

Comment: It worked!! Than you!! :)

But now I'm having another problem, for some reason the button is not working... but if I click in the list Item it works fine...

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri because you do nothing in you adapter onclicklistener' onclick method.

Comment: So i should move the code from my formulasList to the Adapter? I'll try it! Thanks

But In my switch statement inside formulasList i'm getting the item by the "position" to use it inside the adapter should i just use getPosition(); ?